# Cross Platform Random Reproducibility

Tags: android, c++, ios, windows, random

I need to use a random function, but also have it repeating on different devices (PC / iOS / Android).
I'm running this sample code, to shuffle a vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 generator(1337);
    std::cout << "Your seed produced: " << generator() << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), generator);
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output from **two** different PCs (windows):

```
Your seed produced: 1125387415
10 6 8 1 7 2 4 3 5 9
```

Output from iOS:

```
Your seed produced: 1125387415
9 1 4 6 7 8 5 3 10 2
```

Why am I getting different results?
Is there another dependency relating to the OS itself?
How is it possible to get this to work cross-platform?

Comment: make it work just on the server, and then force the clients to use that?

Comment: Your seed is fine, the problem is with `std::shuffle`. Worst comes to worst, use your own implementation.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Emk0Kp2erHFTZdpV Getting the same as iOS, but getting a different one on my linux machine

Comment: more info at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449498/how-to-get-c-mersenne-twister-19937-generator-to-give-the-same-results-on-wind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::mt19937` is rigorously [defined by the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/rand#eng.mers) and has no room for platform specific/implementation defined behaviour, your problem doesn't lie here.

The problem is with `std::shuffle`, which in no way [says *how*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/alg.random.shuffle) it is supposed to use the random number generator, just that is *has* to use it.

Which unfortunately means, if you want a reproducible shuffling behaviour, you might need to [implement your own](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle#Possible_implementation).

Answer (score 0):

The `std::shuffle` function’s third argument changed. It was a function object that should return a value in the range of [0,n). That means you could pass a `std::uniform_int_distribution`. Now it takes a random bit source like `std::mt19937`. Which does your library expect?

Comment: The [documentation for std::shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) also passes an instance of `std::mt19937` as third parameter. OP demonstrated that the generator produces the same value when run once, so we can assume the internal state is the same and future values will match up. The problem is more likely to be in different implementations of `std::shuffle`.

Comment: Oh. I could not get that from your comment, sorry.

Comment: std:: uniform_int_distribution also does not across platforms.